# Why the output of the code below is this map:{1=[Dd,Ff], 2=[Dd,Ff], 3=[Dd,Ff], 4=[Dd,Ff]}?

Tags: java

What I anticipated as output was this:{1=[Aa,Cc], 2=[Bb,Dd], 3=[Cc,Ee], 4=[Dd,Ff]}?
I just wanted to make separate array lists with the adjacent letters for every letter from the array(except for the first and the last ones), and then to put these array lists as values in a map.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
            String[] arr = {"Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd", "Ee", "Ff"};
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> mp = new HashMap<>();
            
            for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
                al.clear(); 
                al.add(arr[i-1]);
                al.add(arr[i+1]);
                mp.put(i,al);
            }
            
            System.out.print(mp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In general, a good way to answer the question, "Why doesn't this code behave the way I expect?" is to use a debugger and step through the code. Popular IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse have built-in support for debugging. Both of those IDEs have free versions anyone can use. Personally I like IntelliJ IDEA, and they have a great tutorial on using their debugger called [Debugging Your First Java Application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html).

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to make separate array lists

That's not what this code does. This code makes *one* array list.

In the loop, instead of clearing the list, create a new one.

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   al = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
```